# Less then or equal to Else IF Java stuck

Tags: java, if-statement

This program enters in a temperature and based on the temperature a message is outputted. My program is getting stuck tempOutside <= 50 message.. When I enter -10 the output is "Time to turn on the heat".  I cannot use && as this is an assignment questions and we have not used this concept.

```
    if (tempOutside > 50)
        System.out.println("Enjoy the weather");
    else if (tempOutside <= 50)
        System.out.println("Time to turn on the heat");
    else if (tempOutside <= 30)
        System.out.println("Check the gas in you car before leaving");
    else if (tempOutside <= -10)
        System.out.println("BUNDLE UP it's \"COLD\" outside ");
    else

  1) if-else must be in numerical order (hi to low)
  2) Default must be coded
  3) Repeat the code, but reverse the order(low to hi)
```

Answer (score 1):

All `int`s are either `> 50` or `<= 50`. The first two conditions match everything.

Change the second condition to

```
> 30
```

And the third condition to

```
> -10
```

Etc.

Answer (score 0):

it would have been more clear if you could have mentioned your exact question directly and then your implementation as it looks like there could be a misunderstanding of the question here.
But I think perhaps this is what is being asked here??

```
if (tempOutside > 50)
    {
        System.out.println("Enjoy the weather");
    }
    else if (tempOutside <= 50)
    {
        if(tempOutside <= 30)
        {
            if(tempOutside <= -10)
            {
                System.out.println("BUNDLE UP it's \"COLD\" outside ");

            }
            else {
            System.out.println("Check the gas in you car before leaving");
            }

        }
        else
        {
            //when the temp is between 30 and 50
            System.out.println("Time to turn on the heat");

        }
    }
```